# What is the right way to add <random> header file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to generate 64-bit random numbers with the use of mersenne_twister_engine but when I try to include `#include <random>`, the compiler gives me a warning shown below

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires      compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options. make: *** [fuse.o] Error 1

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options? What happened?

Comment: Wasn't the compileer warning message self explanatory?

Comment: agree I will take from next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why random header not importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237259/why-random-header-not-importing)

Answer (score 5):

> ... and must be enabled with the `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` compiler options.

Did you not read that bit? You need to add one of those to your compiler command line (or, if you're using an IDE, whatever method your IDE uses to set the options). Details on C++11 support in gcc can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

For example (command line compiling), if your current command is

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp
```

you would change it to something like

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o myprog myprog.cpp
```

Comment: could you please guide me how to add ?

Comment: @DarshitDave, that depends on _how_ you're building (various IDEs, command line, command line via make, etc). I've given an example for command line compiling.

Comment: could you please guide me on how to add this same option in Makefile?

Comment: @DarshitDave, that depends _entirely_ on your makefile. What you basically have to do is figure out how the options are being set for g++. It may be hardcoded into every g++ compile action, it may use CPPFLAGS to affect every compile, it may do any number of things. Bottom line, you have to ensure the command line made by make has that option. Without having the makefile, we can't help you out.

Answer (score 1):

`random` is introduced in C++11 so add this to your g++ option:

```
--std=c++0x
```

or

```
--std=gnu++0x
```

The option is probably in your makefile.

Comment: No that option is not available in my make file. Could you please guide me how to add that option.