# Why random header not importing

Tags: c++, random, include

I have written code in C++ and compiled it by typing `make`. An error occurs:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
>   with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: Perhaps follow the error message and add that to the command line

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to correct it by editing your Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add "-std=c++11" to your compiler arguments, telling it that it is a C++11 compile

`$ g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program`

If you are using some IDE, you need to search the documentation to find out how to add this line so the compiler knows.

Answer (score 1):

The random library is using a newer version of the C++ standard (C++11). You need to modify your makefile to use the -std=c++11 flag. If you post your makefile contents I could advise you further, otherwise look at this question: [Makefile modification to support c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787126/makefile-modification-to-support-c11)

Based on the cmakefile posted, add these lines to your cmakefile:

```
set_property(TARGET abc PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET abc PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

Comment: Are you using make only or cmake then make? Did you get that makefile from another project?

Comment: Well in that case the cmakefile is generating the makefile, so you need to post it instead

Comment: I have to add the lines as it is or make modifications to say TARGET or prog or PROPERTY?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82439/discussion-between-wheeldog-and-giffy).