# Unable to include "random" header file in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files

I have gcc version 4.8.4, but when I add the header file `#include <random>`, it gives me error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
```

Comment: So, you added `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to your compiler options, right?  And then it stopped complaing?  If not, you need to be more specific about how you compile.  (Actually, with such an old GCC, it might accept only `-std=c++0x` instead of`-std=c++11`).

Comment: @TobySpeight don't you just love it when the answer is part of the question?

Comment: No i have not added that.

Comment: @TobySpeight how can I edit that? can you please help me I am new in C++

Comment: The error message is exceptionally clear to me. It say why it doesn't work: Not supported by the compiler. And describes how to enable the compiler support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why random header not importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237259/why-random-header-not-importing)

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
>   with the `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` compiler options.

So you need to ensure that you pass `-std=c++11` (for standard C++) or `-std=gnu++11` (for GNU extensions to standard C++) to your compilation command.  For example:

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall myfile.cc -o myfile
```

I'd advise also moving to a newer version of GCC if you can, so that C++11 is properly supported rather than "experimental".